# line from min to max of a digital elevation model

Tags: qgis, dem, geometry

I have some geometries as multipolygons and a dem (digital elevation model).
I need a line from the max value to the lowest value of the dem for every multipolygon.
Is qgis a tool i could use or do i need PostGIS ?
How could i realize this problem ?

Comment: exactly: the line is inside the multipolygon from the min to the max where the dem overlaps with the multipolygon